# Why I got segmentation fault while free array of string from other function?

Tags: c

This is my code. Please tell me if I have wrong with this code.
code:

```
char **arrofstr(void)
{
    char **ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret)*3);

    ret[0] = strdup("idx0");
    ret[1] = strdup("idx1");
    ret[2] = '\0';

    return ret;
}

void freearr(char ***ptr)
{
    int i=0;

    while(*ptr[i] != '\0')
    {
        free(*ptr[i]);
        printf("free(ptr[%d])\n", i);
        i++;
    }
    free(*ptr);
}

int main(void)
{
    char **arr = arrofstr();
    int i=0;

    while(arr[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%s\n");
        i++;
    {

    freearr(&arr);

    return 0;
}
```

This is output from terminal after I compile
output:

```
$ ./arrofstr
idx0
idx1
free(ptr[0])
segmentation fault
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code, I use gcc 3.1.0.

Comment: "Please check my code" is not completely relevant request for the community. Please specify what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: `***`-ALARM!! ALARM!! All hands brace for impact!! ALARM!! ALARM!!

Comment: Seeing what `freearr()` does it is not necessary to pass a `char***`.

Comment: anything more than 2 pointers is like 5th dimension

Comment: and your program wont compile because of while with 2 open braces

Answer (score 1):

```
free(*ptr[i]);
```

The `*` operator get's executed after `[i]` operator, see [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). So the code first jumps `i * sizeof(*ptr)` bytes, then dereferences. You want:

```
free((*ptr)[i]);
```

Also turn on compile warnings `-Wall` and don't assign integer value `'\0'` (equal to 0x00) to pointer. Use `NULL` for that.

@edit
So, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char **arrofstr(void)
{
    char **ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret)*3);

    ret[0] = strdup("idx0");
    ret[1] = strdup("idx1");
    ret[2] = NULL;

    return ret;
}

void freearr(char ***ptr)
{
    int i=0;

    while((*ptr)[i] != NULL)
    {
        free((*ptr)[i]);
        printf("free(ptr[%d])\n", i);
        i++;
    }
    free(*ptr);
}

int main(void)
{
    char **arr = arrofstr();
    int i=0;

    while(arr[i] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    freearr(&arr);   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I debugged your version and as @Kamil pointed out `free((*ptr)[i])`  also his version may not work because of `printf("%s\n")` so Here's one that I tested :

```
#include <stdio.h>

char **arrofstr(void)
{
    char **ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret)*3);

    ret[0] = strdup("idx0");
    ret[1] = strdup("idx1");
    ret[2] = NULL;

    return ret;
}

void freearr(char ***ptr)
{
    int i=0;

    while((*ptr)[i] != NULL)
    {
        free((*ptr)[i]);
        printf("free(ptr[%d])\n", i);
        i++;
    }
    free(*ptr);
}

int main(void)
{
    char **arr = arrofstr();
    int i=0;
    while(arr[i] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    freearr(&arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @KamilCuk your explanation of `free(*ptr[i])` was very good, I was going to explain it but u published a clearer one ;)